# Custom URL scheme - paramters on custom post type

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I have a custom post type set up as Event. Within this post type I have various bit's of content / custom meta which will be used on two or three different pages.

I was wondering lets say I had my custom post type url as

`http://www.mysite.com/my-custom-post-title/`

and on that page I had 3 links that when clicked would load the relevant content i.e.

`http://www.mysite.com/my-custom-post-title/faqs/`

`http://www.mysite.com/my-custom-post-title/directions/`

I could achieve what I want with query string parameters on the initial URL but was wondering if I could use pretty URL's rather than have `http://www.mysite.com/my-custom-post-title/?subconten=faqs`

I know you can do your own rewrites I am just not sure how best to approach it.

Update:

So assuming I have the following URL:

`http://www.mysite.com/events/my-custom-post-title/info/directions/`

I have added the following action

`add_action('init','custom_rewrites');
function custom_rewrites() {
  global $wp,$wp_rewrite,$wp_query;
  $wp->add_query_var('content_filter');
  $wp_rewrite->add_rule('events/([^/]+)/info/([^/]+)/', 'index.php?post_type=portfolio&name=$matches[1]&content_filter=$matches[2]', 'top');
  $wp_rewrite->flush_rules(false);

  //  print_r(  $wp_rewrite );
}`

Still nothing - I have found that if I dump query vars to the screen on the 404 page "direction" returns as attachment. Anyone have an idea how I can get this working?

Steve

Comment: Ok so here is an update:

Answer (score 0):

Try [rewrite endpoints](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_endpoint):

```
function wpse_143634_endpoint() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'info', EP_PERMALINK );
}

add_action( 'init', 'wpse_143634_endpoint' );
```

Now you'll find you can visit any post and tack on `info/whatever` to the URL - WordPress will still load the post, except now you'll have `get_query_var( 'info' ) == 'whatever'`.

Further reading: https://make.wordpress.org/plugins/2012/06/07/rewrite-endpoints-api/